# Find number of ways to choose $3n$-subset with repetitions from set $\left\{A,B,C\right\}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, polynomials

Find number of ways to choose $3n$-subset with repetitions from set $\left\{A,B,C\right\}$ such that: 
1. Letter $A$ occur at most $2n$
2. Letter $B$ occur at most $2n$
3. Letter $C$ occur odd times

### Approach

I want to use there enumerators. Ok, so a factor responsible for $A$ will be
$$(1+x+x^2+ \cdots + x^{2n}) $$
(We can choose $A$ $0$ times, $1$ time, ... $2n$ times). The same will be for $B$. 
 
Enumerator for $C$ will be
$$(x+x^3+x^5 + \cdots) $$
(We can choose $C$ 1 time, 3 times, etc)

Ok, so I want to find 
$$[x^{3n}](1+x+x^2+ \cdots + x^{2n})(1+x+x^2+ \cdots + x^{2n})(x+x^3+x^5 + \cdots) = $$
$$ [x^{3n}] \left(\frac{1-x^{2n+1}}{1-x}\right)^2 \cdot\frac{x}{1-x^2} $$
but... how I can get from there factor at $x^{3n}$?

Comment: Your work suggests that you meant letter $A$ occurs *at most* $2n$ times and that letter $B$ occurs *at most* $2n$ times.  It is not possible for letters $A$ and $B$ to occur at least $2n$ times since $2n + 2n = 4n > 3n$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes, english is not my native language and I missed words

Comment: Shouldn't the term $\left(\frac{1 - x^{2n + 1}}{1 - x}\right)$ be squared since there are two factors of $(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{2n})$?

Comment: Right, fixed but still I don't know how to use there enumerators. I know that I can do this in other combinatorics approaches but I am especially interested in use there enumerators. Enumerators were created for computers but we should be able to solve that too :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
\begin{align}
(1+x+\ldots+x^{2n})^2 &= \sum_{i=0}^{n}x^{2i}+2\sum_{i=1}^{2n}x^i+2x\sum_{i=2}^{2n}x^i+\ldots2x^{2n-1}x^{2n}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n}x^{2i}+2\sum_{j=0}^{2n-1}\left(x^j\sum_{i=j+1}^{2n}x^i\right).
\end{align}
So, we have
\begin{multline}
(1+x+\ldots+x^{2n})^2 (x+x^3+\ldots) \\=\left[ \sum_{i=0}^{n}x^{2i} \right]\left[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{2k-1}\right]+2\sum_{j=0}^{2n-1}\left[\sum_{i=j+1}^{2n}x^{i+j}\right]\left[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{2k-1}\right]
\end{multline}
We find the coefficient of $x^{3n}$ in the above expression for two separate cases:

**Case 1: $n$ is odd**

- $x^{3n}$ in $\left[ \sum_{i=0}^{n}x^{2i} \right]\left[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{2k-1}\right]$ is due to the terms corresponding to 
  \begin{equation}
  (2i,2k-1)=(0,3n), (2,3n-2), \ldots, (3n-1,1).
  \end{equation}
  Thus, the  coefficient of $x^{3n}$ = $\frac{3n+1}{2}$.
- For $j$ odd, $x^{3n}$ in $2\left[\sum_{i=j+1}^{2n}x^{i+j}\right]\left[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{2k-1}\right]$ is due to the terms corresponding to 
  \begin{equation}
  (i+j,2k-1)=(2j+2,3n-2j-2), (2j+4,3n-2j-4), \ldots, (2n+j-1,n-j+1),
  \end{equation}
  for $i+j\leq 3n-1$ and $j\leq\frac{3n-1}{2}-1$. Thus, the  coefficient of $x^{3n}$ is given by
  \begin{equation}
  \min\{3n-2j-1,2n-j-1\} =  \begin{cases}
  2n-j-1&\text{ for } 1\leq j\leq n\\
  3n-2j-1&\text{ for } n< j\leq \frac{3n-1}{2}-1
  \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
- For $j$ even, $x^{3n}$ in $2\left[\sum_{i=j+1}^{2n}x^{i+j}\right]\left[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{2k-1}\right]$ is due to the terms corresponding to 
  \begin{equation}
  (i+j,2k-1)=(2j+2,3n-2j-2), (2j+4,3n-2j-4), \ldots, (2n+j,n-j),
  \end{equation}
  for $i+j\leq 3n-1$ and $j\leq\frac{3n-1}{2}-1$. Thus, the  coefficient of $x^{3n}$ is given by
  \begin{equation}
  \min\{3n-2j-1,2n-j\} =  \begin{cases}
  2n-j&\text{ for } 1\leq j\leq n-1\\
  3n-2j-1&\text{ for } n-1< j\leq \frac{3n-1}{2}-1
  \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

Thus, the required coefficient is given by
\begin{equation}
\frac{3n+1}{2}+\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{3n-1}{2}-1}(2n-j)+\sum_{j=n}^{\frac{3n-1}{2}-1}(n-j-1) - \frac{n-1}{2} = \frac{7n^2+6n+3}{4}.
\end{equation}

**Case 2: $n$ is even**

- $x^{3n}$ does not appear in $\left[ \sum_{i=0}^{n}x^{2i} \right]\left[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{2k-1}\right]$. Thus, the  coefficient of $x^{3n}=0$.
- For $j$ odd, $x^{3n}$ in $2\left[\sum_{i=j+1}^{2n}x^{i+j}\right]\left[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{2k-1}\right]$ is due to the terms corresponding to 
  \begin{equation}
  (i+j,2k-1)=(2j+1,3n-2j-1), (2j+3,3n-2j-3), \ldots, (2n+j,n-j),
  \end{equation}
  for $j+i\leq 3n-1$ and $j\leq \frac{3n}{2}-1$. Thus, the  coefficient of $x^{3n}$ is given by
  \begin{equation}
  \min\{3n-2j,2n-j+1\} = \begin{cases}
  2n-j+1&\text{ for } 1\leq j\leq n-1\\
  3n-2j&\text{ for } n-1<j\leq \frac{3n}{2}-1
  \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
- For $j$ even, $x^{3n}$ in $2\left[\sum_{i=j+1}^{2n}x^{i+j}\right]\left[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{2k-1}\right]$ is due to the terms corresponding to 
  \begin{equation}
  (i+j,2k-1)=(2j+1,3n-2j-1), (2j+3,3n-2j-3), \ldots, (2n+j-1,n-j+1),
  \end{equation}
  for $j+i\leq 3n-1$ and $j\leq \frac{3n}{2}-1$.  Thus, the  coefficient of $x^{3n}$ is given by
  \begin{equation}
  \min\{3n-2j,2n-j\} = \begin{cases}
  2n-j&\text{ for } 1\leq j\leq n\\
  3n-2j&\text{ for } n<j\leq \frac{3n}{2}-1
  \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

Thus, the required coefficient is given by
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{3n}{2}-1}(2n-j)+\sum_{j=n+1}^{\frac{3n}{2}-1}(n-j) + n/2 = \frac{7n^2+6n}{4}.
\end{equation}

Overall, the number of possibilities is $\frac{7n^2+6 n+3\alpha}{4}$, where
\begin{equation}
\alpha = \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } n \text{ is odd}\\
0, & \text{if } n \text{ is even}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

P.S.: Thanks for introducing the technique of solving using enumerators to me.

Comment: Your work has been invaluable to me! Thanks for great explanation. As you see, it is really interesting method but also hard. I think that it is better for computer than for us, but we should understand it too. Thanks again!

Comment: There were some calculation mistakes which I have now corrected!

Answer (score 0):

**Premises**

We'll use this notation:

$$\alpha=\text{number of repetitions of letter } A$$
$$\beta=\text{number of repetitions of letter } B$$
$$\gamma=\text{number of repetitions of letter } C$$

Clearly a generic permutation with repetition is:

$$P_{3n,(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)}=\frac{3n!}{\alpha!\beta!\gamma!}$$

We can distinguish 4 cases

**1° case: $n$ is odd and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are even**

So:
$$\alpha=2a$$
$$\beta=2b$$
$$\alpha=2c+1$$

In this case the number of $3n$-subsets is clearly:

$$\sum_{a=0}^{n}\sum_{b=0}^{n} \frac{3n!}{2a!2b!(3n-2a-2b)!}$$

**2° case: $n$ is odd and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are odd**

So:
$$\alpha=2a+1$$
$$\beta=2b+1$$
$$\alpha=2c+1$$

In this case the number of $3n$-subsets is clearly:

$$\sum_{a=0}^{n}\sum_{b=0}^{n} \frac{3n!}{(2a-1)!(2b-1)!(3n-2a-2b+2)!}$$

So if $n$ is odd the answer is:

$$\sum_{a=0}^{n}\sum_{b=0}^{n} \left[\frac{3n!}{(2a-1)!(2b-1)!(3n-2a-2b+2)!}+ \frac{3n!}{2a!2b!(3n-2a-2b)!}\right]$$

If $n$ is even the reasoning is the same but I can't find any further simplification :( .

Comment: it is interesting apporach but as I said, I really want to solve that with enumerators

Comment: Since all 'A's and 'B's are identical, you do not have to consider a permutation of 'A's and 'B's, once their number repetition is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> We obtain for $n\geq  1$:
>
> \begin{align*}
> [x^{3n}]&\left(\frac{1-x^{2n+1}}{1-x}\right)^2\frac{x}{1-x^2}\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^{3n-1}]\frac{1-2x^{2n+1}}{(1-x)^2\left(1-x^2\right)}\tag{2}\\
> &=\left([x^{3n-1}]-2[x^{n-2}]\right)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-2}{k}(-x)^k\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^{2j}\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In  (2) we apply the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$ and we expand the numerator skipping the term  $x^{4n+2}$ which  does not contribute to $[x^{3n-1}]$.
- In (3) we  apply the rule from (2) again and do a *[geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* and a *[binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* series expansion.

> Next we calculate the coefficient of $x^n$. We obtain from (3)
> \begin{align*}
> [x^n]&\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^{2j}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+1}{1}x^k\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor}[x^{n-2j}]\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)x^k\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor}(n-2j+1)\tag{6}\\
> &=(n+1)\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor}1-2\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor}j\\
> &=(n+1)\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}+1\right\rfloor\right)-\frac{n}{2}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}+1\right\rfloor\right)\\
> &=\begin{cases}
> (n+1)\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)-\frac{n}{2}\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)&\qquad\qquad\qquad n\text{ even}\\
> (n+1)\left(\frac{n-1}{2}+1\right)-\frac{n-1}{2}\left(\frac{n-1}{2}+1\right)&\qquad\qquad\qquad n\text{ odd}\\
> \end{cases}\\
> &=\begin{cases}
> \frac{1}{4}(n+2)^2&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\  n\text{ even}\\
> \frac{1}{4}(n+2)^2-\frac{1}{4}&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\ n\text{ odd}\tag{7}\\
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (4) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{p-1}(-1)^q$.
- In (5) we apply again $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$ and we set the upper limit of the outer sum to $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$ since the coefficient is non-negative.
- In (6) we select the coefficient of $x^{n-2j}$.

We can now evaluate (3) with the help of (7) and note that if $n$ is even we have odd $3n-1$ and even $n-2$. On the other hand if $n$ is odd we have even $3n-1$ and odd $n-2$.

> We obtain from (3) and (7)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{3n}]}&\color{blue}{\left(\frac{1-x^{2n+1}}{1-x}\right)^2\frac{x}{1-x^2}}\\
> &=\left([x^{3n-1}]-2[x^{n-2}]\right)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-2}{k}(-x)^k\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^{2j}\\
> &=\begin{cases}
> \frac{1}{4}(3n+1)^2-\frac{1}{4}-2\cdot\frac{1}{4}n^2&\qquad\qquad\qquad n\text{ even}\\
> \frac{1}{4}(3n+1)^2-2\left(\frac{1}{4}n^2+\frac{1}{4}\right)&\qquad\qquad\qquad n\text{ odd}\\
> \end{cases}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{4}\left(7n^2+6n+3[[n\text{ odd}]]\right)}\tag{8}
> \end{align*}

In (8) we use *[Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)* as compact notation for even and odd cases.