# Find the generating function to determine the number of ways to choose k objects from n objects when the ith object appears at least n + i times

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Find the generating function to determine the number of ways to choose k objects from n objects when the ith object appears at least n + i times for 1 ≤ i ≤ n.

the generating function for picking k objects from n objects is $(1+x)^{n}$,but I'm  not sure how to go from this to taking into account "the ith object appears at least n + i times"

I am a beginner to this so if you could explain your steps to help me understand why it is things happen, I'd appreciate it

Comment: That link just takes me back to my own question

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I accidentally copied the URL from the browser tab with this post instead of the correct one. The appropriate link is [How can I learn about generating functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3142386/how-can-i-learn-about-generating-functions/3142387).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generating function to ensure that the $i^\text{th}$ object appears at least $n+i$ times is as follows:
\begin{equation}
g(x) = \underset{1^{\text{st}} \text{ object}}{\underbrace{(x^{n+1}+x^{n+2}+\ldots+x^k)}}\underset{2^{\text{nd}} \text{ object}}{\underbrace{(x^{n+2}+x^{n+3}+\ldots+x^k)}}\ldots\underset{n^{\text{th}} \text{ object}}{\underbrace{(x^{2n}+x^{2n+1}+\ldots+x^k)}}.
\end{equation}

Here, the power of $x$ in the first term of the product represents the number of times the first object is picked. Since the first object appears at least $n+1$ times, the smallest power of $x$ in the first term is $n+1$. The maximum number of objects to be chosen is $k$, and hence, the maximum power is $k$. Similarly, we get the later terms. Finally,  the number of ways to choose $k$ objects is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the generator function $g(x)$.

Comment: Nice breakdown! So if we were talking about a generating function the number of ways to pick k objects from n objects when repetitions are not allowed. The generating function for 1 object would be (1+x) ,now if you do that for all n objects you have $(1+x)^{n}$. Is there similarly a way to condense or simplify this function?

Comment: I don't know! :) Looks like it is difficult to solve this question using generator functions! In some cases, it helps. For example, see this answer:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3168665/find-number-of-ways-to-choose-3n-subset-with-repetitions-from-set-left-a-b/3170516?noredirect=1#comment6528328_3170516