# Generating function to pick k objects from n objects under condition that $i^{th}$ object appears $i+jn$ times?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Let $a_{j,k}$ be the number of strings of length $k$, formed from an alphabet of size $n$, such that the $i$th character in the alphabet appears $i+jn$ times in the string.

For example, if $n=3,k=15,j=1$ and the three characters of the alphabet are $a,b,c$ then one such string is $aaaabbbbbcccccc$ and $a_{1,15}$ is the number of rearrangements of this string.

I am trying to find a generating function for the $a_{j,k}$.

Clearly, if $k\ne \sum_{1\le i\le n}(i+jn)$ then $a_{j,k}=0$

I am aware that the general function to generate $n$ elements is $G(x) = (1+x)^{n}$ derived from the binomial theorem.

I have already looked at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3179148/find-the-generating-function-to-determine-the-number-of-ways-to-choose-k-objects) and thought that I could simply plug $j$ into the function:

$G(x) = (x^{1+jn} + x^{2+jn}+...+x^{k})(x^{2+jn} + x^{3+jn}+...+x^{k})...(x^{n+jn} + x^{n+jn+1}+...+x^{k})$

I am unsure as to whether the above function is mathematically correct since I do not fully understand the steps to create a generating function which takes into account this condition.

How would you create a generating function that would satisfy the condition that the $i^{th}$ element must appear $i + jn$ times, assuming $1 ≤ i ≤ n$ and $j \geq 0$? What are the steps in creating this function?

Comment: Are there $n$ objects, or are there $n$ types of object and $\sum_{1\le i \le n}i+jn$ objects? Does it matter what order the $k$ chosen objects are chosen in?

Comment: @AngelaRichardson There are only $n$ objects, without regard to type. I do not believe the order matters, since these generating functions deal with combinations rather than permutations.

Comment: $i+jn>n$ so how can a subset of these $n$ objects have the same object appearing $i+jn$ times?

Comment: @AngelaRichardson Sorry, I meant to say that the number of total objects to choose from is $n$, but any given subset (combination) that is chosen is of size $k$. $k$ may be less than, equal to, or greater than $n$, but must be greater than or equal to 0. The subset is of size $k$, not $i+jn$. I think $i$ is just to refer to a particular element in the generating function.

Comment: So are you asking for the number of strings of length $k$ formed from an alphabet of $n$ characters such that the $i$th character in the alphabet appears $i+jn$ times in the string?

Comment: @AngelaRichardson That is correct. More specifically, the generating function which represents this quantity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106485/discussion-between-angela-richardson-and-thicc).